# Xamarin Forms GoogleMaps data from list to pin and info window

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem. I have a short list of clients and for each of them I want to display a pin and Popup window, which will be displayed after clicking the info window. However, I have no idea how to connect it.

Part of my code:

```
   List<Client> lstClients = new List<Client>
        {
            new Client(1, "Firma 1", "Wspólna 10", "123-123-23-23", "F1", true),
            new Client(2, "Firma 2", "Marszałkowska", "456-456-56-45", "F2", false),
            new Client(3, "Firma 3", "Jerozolimskie 57", "789-789-89-78", "F3", true),
            new Client(4, "Firma 4", "Koszykowa 10", "234-423-43-23", "F4", false)
        };

        foreach (Client client in lstClients)
        {
            var geoadres = client.Address;
            var locations = await Geocoding.GetLocationsAsync(client.Address);

            var location = locations?.FirstOrDefault();
            ListPin = new Pin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Label = client.FirmName,
                Address = client.Address,
                Position = (new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude)),
                Rotation = 33.3f,
                Tag = client.Tag

            };
            map.Pins.Add(ListPin);
        }


   void InfoWindow_Clicked(object sender, InfoWindowClickedEventArgs e)
    {

        PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new ShowPopup());


    }
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: at now  can you able to add pin on map and its displaying on map?

Comment: Yes. I can display all the pins but, I don't know how to display data on popup window.

Comment: I update in answer, check

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on the pin need to show the pop up window, you can implement like this;

```
 foreach (Client client in lstClients)
    {
        var geoadres = client.Address;
        var locations = await Geocoding.GetLocationsAsync(client.Address);

        var location = locations?.FirstOrDefault();
        ListPin = new Pin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Label = client.FirmName,
            Address = client.Address,
            Position = (new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude)),
            Rotation = 33.3f,
            Tag = client.Tag

        };
        map.Pins.Add(ListPin);

        // tap event from map pinview -> Callout action
                map.Pins[i].Clicked += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(((Pin)sender).Type);
                    DisplayAlert(((Pin)sender).Label, ((Pin)sender).Address, "OK");
                };
    }
```

add the code inside for-loop

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use display alert due to the fact the window i want to show must be customable and I have to use something like this https://dzone.com/articles/xamarinforms-custom-popup

Comment: Yes, inside the map pin clicked action you can call the popup window. For custom popup go through this link https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT, you need to open the popup window when map pin icon is clicked right?